# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas' in RStudio

Tags: python, rstudio, virtualenv

I am trying to get my python work in RStudio version 1.4. I cannot run any code python script within RStudio.

For example I run:

```
import pandas as pd
```

And get error such as:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
```

I went into Tool -> Global Options and set up my Python environment to the latest version.

Can someone help me with this? It must be within RStudio IDE.